# ¿Enviar notificación en diferentes idiomas con FireBase Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase

Después de implementar FCM en mi app me saltan dudas, todo esto des de consola.

Si voy a enviar una notificación general (a todos los usuario) si que deja elegir el idioma del mensaje:

[image: Consola Firebase Google]

Pero si quiero enviar a un público selecto através de los topics no deja seleccionar el idioma de envío:

[image: Consola Firebase Google]

¿como debería gestionar los topics para que cada uno reciba la notificación en su idioma?

¿Tendría que detectar el idioma en la app y de esta manera subscribirse a un tema o a otro (ej. topic:lol_esp, topic:lol_eng, etc..)? este método me parecería un poco raro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he creado los topics dependiendo del archivo string.xml que utilicen.

```
     //primara vez que se abre notificacion por defecto EN SU IDIOMA
     String topic = "lolvideos_basic_" + getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.idioma_defecto);
     FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);
     String h = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
     new RegistrarFireToken().execute(h);
```